# Else if in angular js template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use else if in angularjs template .What is the syntax ?
For example in c i would write the code like below:

```
if (data.sender=='system')
{data.receiver}
else if (data.sender=='mail')
{data.receiver} 
else {data.sender}
```

My code:

```
{{data.sender == 'System' ? data.receiver : ' '}}

{{data.sender =='mail' ? data.receiver : data.sender  }}
```

Comment: it might be more clear to make it a computed property.

Comment: i am not looking for if else but "else if"!

Comment: btw your second snippet is in contradiction with the first...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
{{(data.sender === 'system' || data.sender === 'mail') ? data.receiver : data.sender}}
```

Comment: You probably should think of making a filter instead of nested ternary operators.

Comment: yes this answer is only to OP's case, but not general

Comment: Thanks i was making the logic complex!

Comment: What is I have 3 different cases, this won't work.

Answer (score 8):

There are no if-else syntax in angular templates as you are looking for.  Too much logic in the templates makes it difficult to maintain.  Here are two possible solutions:

```
<span ng-show="data.sender == 'mail' || data.sender=='system'">{{data.receiver}}</span>
<span ng-show="data.sender != 'mail' && data.sender!='system'">{{data.sender}}</span>
```

You can also use ng-switch in a similar way:

```
<span ng-switch="data.sender">
    <span ng-switch-when="mail">{{data.receiver}}</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="system">{{data.receiver}}</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>{{data.sender}}</span>
</span>
```

The later having the advantage that only one of the spans will exist in the document where ng-show/ng-hide all spans exist in the document they are just hidden using display:none.

Other options would be writing your own directive, or creating special filters.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, but you should really try to avoid having this kind of complicated logic inside of templates, as a rule of thumb.

```
{{ data.sender == 'system' ? data.receiver : data.sender == 'mail' ? data.receiver : data.sender }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need an **elseif** in angular template you can use a ternary operator as in C/C++

```
 {{ data.sender=='system'
< 4 ? data.receiver : data.sender=='mail' ? data.receiver : data.sender}}
```

```js
angular.module('quetion_app', []);

angular.module('quetion_app').controller('quertion_controller', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.data = {
      sender: 'some sender',
      receiver: 'somebody'
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="quetion_app">

  <div ng-controller="quertion_controller">
    {{data}}
    <br>
    <br>
    {{ data.sender=='system'
    < 4 ? data.receiver : data.sender=='mail' ? data.receiver : data.sender}} </div>

  </div>
```

Change **data.sender** in snippet to check the behavior

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This type of logic really belongs in the controller or service which is responsible for setting up data in your $scope. Placing it in your view brings a lot of logic in to the view unnecessarily and also causes that logic to be run as a watch which both expensive and unnecessary.

In the code that establishes data you could have:

```
data.displayedSender = (data.sender === 'system' || data.sender === 'mail') ? data.receiver : data.sender;
```

Then in your view you bind to the `data.displayed` sender:

```
<span>{{data.displayedSender}}</span>
```